# Rails 4.1.6 app with refinerycms and activeadmin

Tags: integration, activeadmin, refinerycms, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a rails 4.1.6 app that has refinerycms integrated and it is going well. I was asked to integrate activeadmin also into my app. I just added gem activeadmin and generated the active admin files using active admin generator.

When I navigated to `localhost:300/admin`, I'm not getting activeadmin login page instead I am getting devise routes undefined.

means errorr like : `undefined method admin_new_user_session_path`

I don't have clear Idea what is causing not to identify devise routes for active admin.

Please tell me if there are any big challenges that I have to take care of  while integrating activeadmin with refinerycms.

**Note**: The refinerey CMS is integrated to a level [exrend models& controllers with refinery](http://www.refinerycms.com/guides/extending-models)

**Note**: It is very much helpful if I can get a tutorial that integrates refinerycms and activeadmin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with *activeadmin*. But the error seems like there might be an incompatibility between the default *refinery* and *activeadmin* routes. Usually, in a rails app one needs to modify the routes in the *config/routes.rb* file manually, so that the url requests go to the right controller. However, refinery is an engine, and there is only one line in the *routes.rb* file in the usual refinery project:

```
mount Refinery::Core::Engine, at: Refinery::Core.mounted_path.
```

If your activeadmin requests get routed to the refinery engine, that produce such errors as:

```
undefined method ...
```

Hope this helps!
Cheers!